# Using a TESmart KVM with Intel Macbook pro. External displays not identifying correctly

Tags: macbook-pro, kvm

So, I just decided to get a KVM because switching inputs was annoying for my work at home setup. The issue I'm running into though is that the macbook doesn't identify my 2 external displays correctly on connect. It requires a reboot for them to identify correctly.

When they are identified incorrectly, they come up as "ITE-FHD" instead of the "LG 4k HDR" identifier they normally show. The resolution is terrible and the colors are completely off.

Anyone have any advice? I'm mostly a Windows/Linux user, and use the macbook for work as required.

Edit to add: rebooting the macbook fixes the issue, but this happens anytime it wakes from sleep, which is often when I step away from the desk for a bit.

Comment: The usual first fix for this is to force the screens to wake first - by pressing any button if they have one - it's usually that they're not ready when the Mac is.

Comment: You seem to be correct here. Shame that it doesn't handle the same way as my PC ruining CentOS and Windows. Oh well. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The issues are caused by the KVM switch does not provide full-time EDID emulation/feeding to all connected systems (both your Linux system and MacBook).

So, each time you want to make a switch to different connected systems or if the monitor connections are under power saving time-out, you will need to re-boot or replug cables to make re-initial the video bus communications between your shared monitor and connected systems.

It's a very command problem with most of the KVM switches not supporting EDID feeding functions.

Find a DDM-class KVM switch will solve the issues.